# I cannot import class of one file to another in a subfolder in Java using vscode

Tags: java, maven, class, visual-studio-code, package

**How can import a class in different directory in subfolders??**

I am new in Java programming language and i want to use a class in other directory by importing their packages but i can't do it !!.

i have a class called Car.

```
package ir.tclas.clasor.models;

public class Car {
private String Models;
private String Name;
private String Color;
private Integer weigth;


public void setWeigth(Integer weigth) {
    if (weigth > 50)
        this.weigth = 45;
    else {
        this.weigth = weigth;
    }

}

public String getModels() {
    if (Models == null)
        Models = "NO_Name";
    return Models;
}


  public void horn() {
  System.out.println("Beeeeeep!!!");
  }
}
```

now i want import Car from MainApp

```
  package ir.tclas.clasor;

  import ir.tclas.clasor.models.Car;

  public class MainApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car bmw = new Car();

    bmw.setName("BMW");
    bmw.setColor("Blue");
    bmw.setWeigth(55);

    bmw.horn();
    System.out.println(bmw.getName());
    System.out.println(bmw.getModels());
    System.out.println(bmw.getColor());
    System.out.println(bmw.getWeigth());
 }
}
```

this is my out put after run my code:

```
 PS E:\java_pj\001\demo> cd 
 "e:\java_pj\001\demo\src\main\java\ir\tclas\clasor\" ; if ($?) { 
 javac MainApp.java } ; if ($?) { java MainApp.java }
 MainApp.java:4: error: package ir.tclas.clasor.models does not exist
 import ir.tclas.clasor.models.Car;
                         ^    
 MainApp.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    Car bmw = new Car();
    ^
 symbol:   class Car
 location: class MainApp
 MainApp.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    Car bmw = new Car();
                  ^
 symbol:   class Car
 location: class MainApp
 3 errors

 PS E:\java_pj\001\demo\src\main\java\ir\tclas\clasor>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I highly recommend you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). This will help you to improve the quality of your questions. **Never post images of your code. Post your code as text and format it as code.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Runner doesn't include packages when compiling .java files and that's why error occurs, you should manually change the command in Settings.json:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "java": "cd e:/java_pj/001/demo/src/main/java && javac ir/tclas/clasor/models/Car.java && javac ir/tclas/clasor/$fileName && java ir/tclas/clasor/$fileNameWithoutExt",       
}
```

[image]

OR you can directly disable the extension Code Runner and run your project by **Java Extension**. After adding getters and setters in `Car.java`, your code works well, and no errors are shown:

[image]